# Why FreqDist comparisons in NLTK are not symmetric? i.e. '>' and '<' behave differently

Tags: python, nltk

```
nltk.FreqDist('abc') > nltk.FreqDist('abd')
```

returns `True`

and

```
nltk.FreqDist('abd') < nltk.FreqDist('abc')
```

returns `False`

What's the reason behind this? It seems a bit weird to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the comparison methods of the `FreqDist` class and found that they are all based on one method: `__le__`. Just to illustrate what that means, given this setup:

```
>>> abc = nltk.FreqDist('abc')
>>> abd = nltk.FreqDist('abd')
```

These two statements are equivalent:

```
>>> abc < abd
False
>>> abc.__le__(abd)
False
```

Now, the first thing this method does is check whether the keys of the first `FreqDist` are a subset of the keys of the second one. In your example this will always be `False`, which is what this method returns.

However, the `>` operator triggers the `__gt__` method to be run, which is written to return the negation of `__le__`. Thus it is that you get `True` as a result.

To be honest, I don't know why comparison methods were added to `FreqDist` at all. Its parent `Counter` doesn't support comparisons and I suspect that's precisely because it's not trivial (to say the least) to come up with a good solution to this. I have a hunch that this code is a relic from the days when `FreqDist` did not inherit from `Counter` and some overzealous OOP fan decided that class needed to support comparisons. I personally struggle to come up with a situation in which this would be useful.

If I were you, I'd open an bug report in [NLTK's issue tracker](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues). Or, if you have time, just open a PR with this stuff removed.